# Apache Beam euphoria Issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have built the apache beam un-official version from github.com/apache/beam their was a new class to use DataSet Facility euphoria but after Putting all the jar in .m2 repository on my PC i am Facing below Issue.

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.esotericsoftware:kryo:jar:4.0.2
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.esotericsoftware:kryo:jar:4.0.2
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:282)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:188)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.getProjectFacade(MavenBuilder.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer com.esotericsoftware:kryo:pom:4.0.2 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.esotericsoftware:kryo:pom:4.0.2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:267)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer com.esotericsoftware:kryo:pom:4.0.2 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.esotericsoftware:kryo:pom:4.0.2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    ... 48 more
```

Any Solution to test it for now/I need to wait for Official Release.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the interest in Euphoria! You can use Apache snapshots repository, in order to use euphoria right now.

https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/beam/

You can add the repository to your maven project as follows:

```
<repository>
    <id>apache.snapshots</id>
    <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
    <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
```

Please note that there will likely be some API changes before the first official release - eg. replacing Dataset abstraction with PCollection.

David